# What Are the Differences Between HAProxy's slim and smax Statistics

Tags: monitoring, haproxy

I'm setting up monitoring for a few HAProxy nodes and noticed that the value HAProxy was returning for both `slim` and `smax` on each node are always the same.  From reading [the documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/management.html#9.1) it sounds like they show equivalent state:

> 5. smax [LFBS]: max sessions
> 6. slim [LFBS]: configured session limit

Is it true that the value of both `smax` and `slim` report the same thing, or do they show something different and what is that difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the HAProxy source it became obvious that these two reported metrics are different things.

- **slim**: The maximum value of sessions HAProxy is configured to accept, as said in the HAProxy documentation.  This doesn't report any active HAProxy performance metric, rather just a convenient reminder of what you set the session limit to be.
- **smax**: The number of sessions HAProxy has run through in a time frame.  HAProxy reports metrics within certain time frame and this metric reports what the total number of sessions used during that time frame was.  So, in other words, it is the running count of active sessions.

It turns out that our HAProxy cluster was just pegged and running though the entirety of all the sessions it was configured to use, thus these metrics appeared equivalent in that situation.